# Deleting a row from a table based on the existence

Tags: sql

This might be a trivial solution. I have searched similar posts regarding this but I couldn't find a proper solution.

I'm trying to delete a row if it exists in a table

I have a table say

```
         Table1
----------------------------
|Database| Schema | Number |
----------------------------
|  DB1   |   S1   |    1   | 
|  DB2   |   S2   |    2   |
|  DB3   |   S3   |    3   | <--- Want to delete this row
|  DB4   |   S4   |    4   |
----------------------------
```

Here is my query

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Database = 'DB3' and Schema = 'S3');
```

When I tried the above SQL, it returned me an empty table, don't understand why it's returning an empty table.

There are similar posts on stack overflow but I couldn't find why I'm getting empty table.

Comment: You don't have to check for it: if it doesn't exist, nothing will be deleted (without throwing an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a subquery?  Just use a `where` clause:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Database = 'DB3' and Schema = 'S3';
```

Your code will delete either *all* rows or *no* rows.  The `where` condition is saying "delete all rows from this table where this subquery returns at least one row".  So, if the subquery returns one row, everything is deleted.  Otherwise, nothing is deleted.